# Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Missing write contacts permission. Expo React Native a pesar de generar una standalone app

Tags: react-native, expo

Ya he agregado el permiso a `app.json`

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "add-contact-list",
    "slug": "add-contact-list",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "android": {
      "package": "the.contacts.adder",
      "permissions": [
        "WRITE_CONTACTS"
       ]
    }
  }
}
```

Y también antes de guardar el contacto, pido permiso al usuario

```
const start = async (params) => {
    const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
    if (status === 'granted') {
        const newContact = {
          [Contacts.Fields.Name]: `JJJ-Prueba`,
          [Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers]: [
            {
                number: '(81) 8420-0123',
                isPrimary: true,
                digits: `8184200123`,
                countryCode: '+52',
                id: `JJJ-UNIQUE`,
                label: `JJJ`,
            },
          ]
        };

        await Contacts.addContactAsync(newContact);
        setCurrentPhoneNumber(phoneNumbers[number]);
    }
}
```

La documentación de expo dice que debo generar un standalone app para android para poder guardar contactos sin embargo ya hice eso y sigo obteniendo el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo en la documentacion te esta faltando encuadrarlo en un UseEffect()
quizas tambien te falto instalar  'expo-contacts'

```
    expo install expo-contacts
```

un ejemplo de lo que aparece en la documentacion (fijate que esta encerrado en un useEffect)

```
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
    import * as Contacts from 'expo-contacts';

    export default function App() {
      useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
          if (status === 'granted') {
            const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
              fields: [Contacts.Fields.Emails],
            });

            if (data.length > 0) {
              const contact = data[0];
              console.log(contact);
            }
          }
        })();
      }, []);

      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Contacts Module Example</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Voy a intentarlo, gracias

Comment: te salio lo que mencione?